# Upgrading drives on a MD3000

Tags: dell, cluster, dell-powervault, partition

Our MD3000 array is getting full as our databases are growing and we need more spaces.
Currently, we use a MD3000 with a two-servers Windows 2003 cluster and 15x 73GB SAS drives.
Disk groups are configured in RAID1 of two drives.

The approach we are currently investigating is simply swapping the existing SAS drives with bigger ones (300GB instead of 73GB), one at a time, and let each RAID1 array rebuilt.

Is it a good approach?
Will we be able to resize the array afterwards?
Will we be able to resize the partitions afterwards? Can the Dell M3000 Management software do it or will we have to bring the server offline and use some partition software to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you take a backup prior to degrading the array's then that is the approach I would recommend. Once you have the new drives in you will be able to either expand existing logical volumes into the new physical space or create new logical volumes that utilize the new space.

Comment: Thanks.
Did you do this before on this equipment?
How is it been done? I have taken a look at the software and I don't really see any option that would let me expand the drives at the moment.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure have - here are the doc's : http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/md3000/en/ug/html/create.htm#wp1011243

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful. Once the virtual disks has been expended, do I need to resize the partitions to afterwards or will the system take care of this at the same time?

Thanks again.

Comment: You would need to resize/grow them in wondows.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I assumed then... so it means I'll have to take down the SQL Server for a while during the operation.

Can you suggest one stable software for that? It is an important production server. Usually when we need to resize partition, we simply use a boot CD but I suspect it will likely not see the MD3000?

Last one question, if you don't mind, will any SAS drives work with it? The Dell manual says that only their drives are supported, but I suspect it to not be the case. Would prefer to make sure before buying a dozen of new drives.

Thanks again for your great help.

Comment: If I were you I would create a new logical drive on the added space. Then format/mount that in windows, with that done you can add the new disk into your SQL Server DB's file groups. This way you needn't have any outage.

As for do any disks work - I cant say yes or no. I know that 90% of the time any disk will work. I know that Dell have started using custom firmware in their server drives and the POST reports the disks as being "not optimal" but they still work.